# Vim trigger abbreviations on underscore?

Tags: vim, abbreviation

I like that _ is treated as a keyword character for most purposes, but for abbreviations I would like _ to trigger an abbreviation.  Is there a way to automatically do this or is my best option to press `<C-]>` before typing the underscore?

Use Case: if I have a long word that I type often, I might have variables containing that long word (e.g. table names of the form myverylongname_foo_table), and would like the abbreviation to activate in the middle of typing that, just after pressing the underscore.

Comment: This can be solved with a map, but there is a part that I didn't understand with your _use case_: do you have abbreviations for all your long names?

Comment: There are a few long names / words I have to type frequently, and I created abbreviations for those.

Comment: ah I see. I posted a map answer, I think this might work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a map to "overwrite" the underscore behavior:

```
inoremap _ <C-]>_
```

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution.  I can set up an auto-command to remove _ from the `iskeyword` definition when I enter insert mode and restore it when I leave.

```
autocmd InsertEnter * setl iskeyword-=_
autocmd InsertLeave * setl iskeyword+=_
```

Comment: This has side-effects I don't want to incur, like screwing up autocompletion.  Will accept an answer that doesn't have these drawbacks.